# flink FoldingStateDescriptor is deprecated message

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, apache-flink

I am using Flink 1.8.0,
Trying to compile this line of code

```
val mockState = mock[KeyedStateStore]
```

with Intellij yields the following error (although that in `sbt` it seems to compile fine)

> Error:(38, 23) class FoldingStateDescriptor in package state is
>   deprecated: see corresponding Javadoc for more information.
>
> `val mockState = mock[KeyedStateStore]`

Although I am not calling the `getFoldingState` which is deprecated . any ideas how to get around that ?